# How to show dropdown expanded automatically so that it displays all the options when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the need to show the DropDown (HTML select element) expanded initially when it is loaded so that all the options in the DropDown are shown. I searched quite a bit, but suprisingly, I did not find an answer to such a simple problem. I am using ASP.NET MVC with jquery.

Comment: Non-direct solutions: 1) make the first option scream out "Select your country.." or the like; 2) use radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write in your HTML code:

```
   <select size="3" name="test" id="test">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
   </select>
```

and then via javascript set a timer that after while changes the select box size attribute to 1.
For instance at the end of your page (before the clsed body tag) place this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('test').size = 1; }, 5000); //5000 = 5 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: This is good enough for letting the user know that the list is populated. Does not work for me. But thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little mashup (that needs tweaking and optimising) but should get you started:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <select style="position: absolute">
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
        <option>option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").one("focus", function() {
        this.size = this.options.length;
    }).one("click", function() {
        this.size = 1;
    }).one("blur", function() {
        this.size = this.options.length;
    }).focus();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The solution is working but I have to set the size back on mouse click anywhere else. But I can easily add that.

Comment: @mohang - Ah, I just added a `blur` event handler that's bound once using `one` to do that (which might be a little neater).

Answer (score 3):

You Could write your **HTML** like this

```
<html>
<select id="abc">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
    <option>option 5</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Below, Is the **JAVASCRIPT** Function that expands automatically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("abc");
        var event;
        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I wish people would write more generic example code, not everyone uses jQuery.

Comment: The question says, "I am using ASP.NET MVC with jquery", and it is tagged 'jquery' and the body of the function IS generic javascript.